# Plot with image in gnuplot error

Tags: file, gnuplot, opensuse, ras

I'm trying to plot with image using gnuplot but it always returns me "Reading ras files from sequential devices not supported". Think of a file named "test.txt" includes:

```
6 5 4 3 1 0
3 2 2 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 2 3
0 0 1 2 4 3
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Using gnuplot:

```
gnuplot> plot "test.txt" matrix  w image
gnuplot> Reading ras files from sequential devices not supported
Reading ras files from sequential devices not supported
```

What can I do about it? Is there any software that I haven't installed in my computer?
I'm using openSuse and I'm not very familiar with it yet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: For me it works fine using gnuplot 4.6.3. Which gnuplot version do you use, which terminal and which OS?

Comment: I' using " gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 3 ", OS 13.1 and as for the terminal, i'm using the bash-konsole.

Comment: what do you get with command "show term" inside gnuplot

Comment: After searching for the error message, it looks like a Qt-related problem, so I'm guessing that it's the Qt terminal.